# using ~/ (user entry) at shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, fedora-25

I failed to accesses "user entry" by shell script, the following commands interrupt errors ( ls: cannot access '~/Workspace': No such file or directory )

```
ls ~/Workspace
ls "~/Workspace"
ls "\~/Workspace"
```

commanding the above via terminal works fine. any ideas? 
I'm using fedora 25 without significant customization. thanks.

Comment: How are you executing the script and do you have #!/bin/bash at the top of the script?

Comment: Have you tried using $HOME variable instead of the ~ ?

Comment: Tilde expansion should work in noninteractive shells too, I don't see anything obviously wrong with the first example. The second two would not work because the tilde is quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the "Workspace" dir exist on home dir for that user?

Anyway, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls $HOME/Workspace
```

Comment: Ok, mark it as solved please. Maybe could be useful for others.